# How to center google ap3 map on marker?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a real estates website where the admin can add properties to his projects page. Now one of the options he should have is to add the place of the property he advertised. On my CMS pan I have the map which the admin will drop his pin to his specific property and then save this. After that the expected clients who will enter the site will see the pin which the admin put before.

Here is my code of the admin section

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var marker;
    var infowindow;

    function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.0599153,31.2620199,13);
      var options = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
      var html = "<table>" +
                 "<tr><td>Name:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
                 "<tr><td>Address:</td> <td><input type='text' id='address'/></td> </tr>" +
                 "<tr><td>Type:</td> <td><select id='type'>" +
                 "<option value='bar' SELECTED>bar</option>" +
                 "<option value='restaurant'>restaurant</option>" +
                 "</select> </td></tr>" +
                 "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>";
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: html
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
    }

    function saveData() {
      var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
      var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
      var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
      var latlng = marker.getPosition();

      var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address +
                "&type=" + type + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
      downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
          infowindow.close();
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
        }
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
    <div id="message"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And then it comes to the PHP code which manage the dynamic part of adding the information to the database:

```
<?php
// Gets data from URL parameters
$name = $_GET['name'];
$address = $_GET['address'];
$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lng = $_GET['lng'];
$type = $_GET['type'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
         die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("arabia");

// Insert new row with user data
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO markers " .
         " (id, name, address, lat, lng, type ) " .
         " VALUES (NULL, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');",
         mysql_real_escape_string($name),
         mysql_real_escape_string($address),
         mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
         mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
         mysql_real_escape_string($type));

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Now come to the clients section.

The HTML of the client section which has the problem, the clients sees the map from here

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>map</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };
    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.0599153,31.2620199,13)||map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Now the last PHP section witch manage getting the data from the database:

```
<?php  

// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
         die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("arabia");

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {  
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
} 

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

Now everything is running fine with this code the whole problem is in this line of code in the HTML of the client view center:

> new
>   google.maps.LatLng(30.0599153,31.2620199,13)||map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()),

which I need it to be centered on the pin that the admin put before.

Comment: it seems that I misunderstood your question. How many markers do you read from database. One or many? If you have many markers how do you know which one is to be used for center? Do you use `type` attribute for that?

Comment: @Anto Jurković How many markers do you read from database? for each project will be one map so the project will read one map by the project id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** This part of answer is valid only for admin side.

Update map click handler with `map.setCenter(event.latLng);`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });

    map.setCenter(event.latLng);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
```

**Update:** This part of answer is for client side.

Map has to be initialized like:

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.0599153,31.2620199,13),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
```

If you have only one marker than you should use method `setCenter()` like (part of `for` loop):

```
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          map.setCenter(point);
```

If you have many markers than you can use method `fitBounds()`, changes in `for` loop:

```
    var latlngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });

          latlngBounds.extend(point);

          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }

    map.fitBounds(latlngBounds);
```

That way map will be set so all markers are visible.

Comment: I did that but no luck I edit the two files client and the admin with your code but still the marker don't get on the center

Comment: I still see it on the same lat lng that I put on this line
`new google.maps.LatLng(30.0599153,31.2620199,13)` I replaced this line to be `center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.0599153,31.2620199,13)||map.setCenter(event.latLng),`

Comment: I don't understand where you put that line? As `center: ` of map initialization? You can use there only valid latLng.

Comment: sorry I very new to this Google Map and the Java I put the line as `center:` on the page where the clients will view the map, can you please if I am wrong show me where can I edit the code with your above code

Comment: The code from answer is good only for admin part. When he click on map, marker will be created and map should be centered at marker. For client side: problem is if you have many markers than you have to decide which marker to use for center or to extend bounds of map to fit all markers. So, question is: do you have one marker for client side or more than one?

Comment: it will be one marker for each property (as this is a real estates website) so each property has it's own marker, just one marker on the map

Comment: @Mikky: I updated the answer, hope that will be helpfull